# How do I locate the custom keyboard shortcuts on the filesystem?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, filesystem, automation, preferences

I have a lot of custom keyboard shortcuts (`System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → App Shortcuts`), but they don't seem to be able to be exported. Is there any way to access them on the filesystem so I can move them to another device?

Comment: Not what you asked, but if you have a new device, you can copy ("migrate") your _entire_ profile, shortcuts included, from one Mac to another.

Comment: @alexis What do you mean by "entire **profile**"?

Comment: All your user preferences, settings, documents, search history, ... basically Macs are designed so that (in theory*) you can keep the contents of your mac and just swap the hardware to a newer model. Here's a [sample set of instructions](https://www.macworld.com/article/231681/how-to-move-a-user-account-from-one-mac-to-another.html).

Comment: * Some restrictions apply. But basic things like keyboard shortcuts should all be included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortcuts are stored per-application at the path `~/Library/Preferences/APP.plist` where `APP` is the reverse URI of the app (eg `com.apple.safari`).

For example, a shortcut like this in Pixelmator:

[image: Alt-B to "Pixel Paint" in Pixelmator Pro.]

would appear at the path `com.pixelmatorteam.pixelmator.x.plist` under the key `NSUserKeyEquivalents`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSUserKeyEquivalents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Pixel Paint</key>
        <string>~b</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

For *all* applications, the file `.GlobalPreferences.plist` holds this key, in and among a few other goodies such as the text replacement settings.

Take note that the `.plist` file may be binary-encoded so you may need an editor (eg [Binary Plist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dnicolson.binary-plist) for VS Code) to view the keys.

---

Shortcuts consist of a single character corresponding to the key prefixed with one or more of the modifier keys:

- `^` for the Control (⌃) key,
- `~` for the Option (⌥) key,
- `@` for the Command (⌘) key,
- `$` for the Shift (⇧) key.

Some keys are represented with unicode symbols typically used in the UI itself:

- Arrows: ←↑→↓
- Tab: ⇥
- Enter: ↩
- Escape: ⎋
- F1 through F12: U+F704 through U+F70F, respectively (and can't be printed).

Comment: To be clear, U+F704 through U+F70F aren't _unprintable_ as such, they're just "Private Use", so their meaning varies from font to font. They might show up as extra emojis, or a fictional alphabet, or non-standard punctuation symbols - anything that someone wants in a font but doesn't have a Unicode code point allocated. Or, in most "mainstream" fonts, they'll simply be left unpopulated, and probably show as a placeholder.

Comment: I've made a tiny little tool to export these to JSON. I'll test out an import function when I next reset my Mac, just to be safe :)  https://github.com/yunruse/macOS-shortcuts

Comment: btw, `.plist` files open fine in Xcode